# Detecting resolution and orientation with php

Tags: php, responsive-design, resolution, landscape

I happen to have this php code that displays records in a gallery. I wish that if a mobile device is vertically oriented and would show only 10 images.

My idea would be to include a conditional depending on resolution have the device to display more or fewer images.

```
require_once("conexion.php");

$RegShow=20;

if(isset($_GET['pag'])){
    $RegistrosAEmpezar=($_GET['pag']-1)*$RegShow
    $PagAct=$_GET['pag'];

}else{
    $RegistrosAEmpezar=0;
    $PagAct=1;
}
```

I'm trying to make a responsive web and not well suited if I put so many images at once.

My problem is I do not know if there was anything to detect with PHP or should serve a different php file using JS depending on the resolution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let `AJAX` download the code or images and insert it into a given tag on client side. You can retrieve the screen information from `javascript` and pass it on to `PHP` using `AJAX POST/GET` request ... and act accordingly.

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY

```
$.ready(function(){
    $.get("images.php?width="+$(window).width()+"&height="+$(window).height(), function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); //or insert the returned data into some div
});
```

});

In images.php

```
<?php

require_once("conexion.php");
$width = $_GET['width'];
$height = $_GET['height'];

//Now you can retrieve accordingly..
```

I hope this gives you enough for a clue, or should I explain more...??

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Very well explained. Let me see if I understood I'm a little fish with javascript. JS and jQuery ready function captured the screen resolution that is running the page and get the variables sent by the width and height so that you can use in php.

So far so good, but the php code is not being read before the javascript code to do its job? Forgive my ignorance, to see if ou can expand on the answer. : D

Comment: I believe there isn't any way to know the screen resolution with a request. You would need JAVASCRIPT to detect the current screen resolution. So first send the requested page, which detects screen resolution and passes it to the PHP, which in turn returns the images accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do this with CSS its more powerfull.
You can use for example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){ //STYLE STUFF }
```

to create different styles for different Resolution

Comment: But they will continue to display the same records. You mean everything to hide and show a div with php different code depending on the resolution?

Comment: The most browser today dont load stuff with "display: none;". But again THE MOST :P

Comment: It could be a solution. But you would have to charge twice the hosting gallery? :O

Comment: @PlayerWet i thought a bit about my idea and i thing you are better with the JS solution